# FancyBox v2.0 script confusion>jquery.fancybox.pack.js OR jquery.fancybox.js

Tags: jquery, fancybox

A bit confused over the 2 different script files included in the download.

jquery.fancybox.pack.js

and

jquery.fancybox.js

In the demo it uses only the latter, but in the read me and instructions it refers to the former. Also, I can't seem to find any dependency between the 2 files.

Can someone shed some light here?

I also noticed that both the thumbnail and button helpers don't work correctly(don't appear) on the iPad but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` version has the code *minified*; it's not the identical source code (should map to same or equivalent tokens) but it has the exact same functionality and a smaller filesize.